# Display database query results as event text (Laravel 7, FullCalendar 5)

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am getting some columns from my database as an event feed from my controller:

```
$events = DB::table('toolplanview')
  ->select('id', 'eventId', 'resourceId', 'title', 'start', 'end')
  ->get();
return json_encode($events);
```

Per default, Calendar displays the `title` on the events but I need to also show the `eventId`. I can get some info using

```
eventContent: function(info) {
  return info.event.title + " (Start: " + info.event.start +")";
},
```

in my Calendar definition in my view but I can't figure out how to access all the other columns from the event feed / query results. I browsed the docs and could not find any array where they might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have non-standard fields in your event objects, then as per the [Event Parsing](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) documentation, fullCalendar will place these inside the `extendedProps` object which becomes part of the event object within fullCalendar.

So to get a field called `eventId` from your original data, you should be able to use `info.event.extendedProps.eventId` to access it. e.g.

```
eventContent: function(info) {
  return info.event.extendedProps.eventId + ": " + info.event.title + " (Start: " + info.event.start +")";
},
```